# Неполучение статического массива из HelperAdmin

Tags: ооп, framework, yii

У меня есть файл/класс::метод, (HelperAdmin.php/HelperAdmin::menuItem()) извлекающий из БД данные для генерации главного меню и подразделов. Чтобы не выполнять запрос к БД дважды, я создал в его классе статический массив. Почему-то после выполнения этого метода (когда меню реально сформировано и я его вижу) я не могу получить этот статический массив. Выглядит примерно так:

```
class HelperAdmin {
        static $arrMenuItems;
                ...
                public static function menuItem() {
                      ....get $items....
                     self::$arrMenuItems = $items;
                     return $items;
                }
        ....
}
```

...т.е., если я повторно вызываю метод:

```
$items=HelperAdmin::menuItem();
```

он возвращает мне всё, как надо. Если же хочу получить массив:

```
$items=HelperAdmin::$arrMenuItems;
```

возвращает null.
Хотелось бы услышать какие-нибудь гипотезы о причинах этого. Если вы считаете, что идея получить данные из статического массива не лучшая с точки зрения архитектуры Yii - рад буду услышать ваши рекомендации.

Answer (score 2):

Хм.. написал такой код

```
class HelperAdmin {
        static $arrMenuItems;

                public static function menuItem() {

                     $items=array(1,2,3);
                self::$arrMenuItems =  $items;
                     return $items;
                }
     }

$items=HelperAdmin::menuItem();
var_dump($items);

$items1=HelperAdmin::$arrMenuItems;
var_dump($items1);
```

вывод

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) } array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) }
```

Смысл я так понимаю я оставил тот же? вызов вы так же делаете?

Comment: Да. Я подозреваю, что проблема не в PHP/ООП, а в архитектуре Yii. Собственно, проблемы, скорее всего, нет, - отсутствует решение задачи. 
Вот схема последовательности:
admin.php:
1. получили данные: 
    $items = HelperAdmin::menuItem();
2. разместили в виджете:
    $this->widget(... 'items'=>$items ...);
После п.1., по идее, $items должны быть сохранены в статическом массиве класса HelperAdmin
3. размещаем контент текущего view (где мне и нужно повторное получение данных): 
    echo $content; - к этому моменту метод HelperAdmin::menuItem(); УЖЕ был вызван, но вместо массива я получаю null.

Answer (score 1):

1. Меню и подобные им детали запилите в Виджет, они были придуманые для подобных целей
2. Че за херня? php4 еще живо?

   ```
   <php
   class MyHelper
   {
       private static $_instance;

       private $_menuItems;

       public static function getInstance()
       {
               if (self::$_instance === null) {
                       self::$_instance = new MyHelper;
               }
               return self::$_instance;
       }

       public function getMenuItem()
       {
               if ($this->_menuItems === null) {
                       $this->_menuItems = array('1','2','3','4');
               }

               return $this->_menuItems;
       }
   }
   ```

И получать данные по `MyHelper::getInstance()->getMenuItem()`.